# How can I dynamically link all other Pages on all Sites in a Navbar in Typo3(11.5.12)?

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I am using Typo3 version 11.5.12 with a sitepackage generated on the [sitepackage builder by Benjamin Kott](https://sitepackagebuilder.com/new/).

I made a Navbar in the partials folder, that I use on every Page on every Site.
It contains links to all Subpages that are on the same Site, however I also want to link all Subpages from all other Sites.
Currently it only shows the children of the Site I am on.

I tried fixing this by making a parent Site where I store all other Sites, however that defeats the purpose of splitting those sites at all.

Is there a way to dynamically link all other Sites?

I made my Navbar using this code:

```
<a href="#" class="open_menu bg-light">
    <f:for each="{mainnavigation}" as="navPoint" iteration="i">
        <div><a href="{navPoint.link}" class="f-heading f-22 link color-white mb-20">{navPoint.title}</a> </div>
    </f:for>
</a>
```

Edit:
[image: Image of the page tree]

Edit 2:
Snippet from setup.typoscript:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    typeNum = 0
    shortcutIcon = EXT:erstes_template/Resources/Public/Icons/favicon.ico

    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        # Template names will be generated automatically by converting the applied
        # backend_layout, there is no explicit mapping necessary anymore.
        #
        # BackendLayout Key
        # subnavigation_right_2_columns -> SubnavigationRight2Columns.html
        #
        # Backend Record
        # uid: 1 -> 1.html
        #
        # Database Entry
        # value: -1 -> None.html
        # value: pagets__subnavigation_right_2_columns -> SubnavigationRight2Columns.html
        templateName = TEXT
        templateName {
            cObject = TEXT
            cObject {
                data = pagelayout
                required = 1
                case = uppercamelcase
                split {
                    token = pagets__
                    cObjNum = 1
                    1.current = 1
                }
            }
            ifEmpty = Default
        }
        templateRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:erstes_template/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
            1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.templateRootPath}
        }
        partialRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:erstes_template/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
            1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.partialRootPath}
        }
        layoutRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:erstes_template/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
            1 = {$page.fluidtemplate.layoutRootPath}
        }
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
            10 {
                references.fieldName = media
            }
            20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
            20 {
                levels = 2
                includeSpacer = 1
                as = mainnavigation
            }
            #
            #I tried to implement the new code here!
            #
        }
    }

    meta {
        viewport = {$page.meta.viewport}
        robots = {$page.meta.robots}
        apple-mobile-web-app-capable = {$page.meta.apple-mobile-web-app-capable}
        description = {$page.meta.description}
        description {
            override.field = description
        }
        author = {$page.meta.author}
        author {
            override.field = author
        }
        keywords = {$page.meta.keywords}
        keywords {
            override.field = keywords
        }
        X-UA-Compatible = {$page.meta.compatible}
        X-UA-Compatible {
            attribute = http-equiv
        }

        # OpenGraph Tags
        og:title {
            attribute = property
            field = title
        }
        og:site_name {
            attribute = property
            data = TSFE:tmpl|setup|sitetitle
        }
        og:description = {$page.meta.description}
        og:description {
            attribute = property
            field = description
        }
        og:image {
            attribute = property
            stdWrap.cObject = FILES
            stdWrap.cObject {
                references {
                    data = levelfield:-1, media, slide
                }
                maxItems = 1
                renderObj = COA
                renderObj {
                    10 = IMG_RESOURCE
                    10 {
                        file {
                            import.data = file:current:uid
                            treatIdAsReference = 1
                            width = 1280c
                            height = 720c
                        }
                        stdWrap {
                            typolink {
                                parameter.data = TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|3
                                returnLast = url
                                forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    includeCSSLibs {

    }

    includeCSS {
        erstes_template_layout = EXT:erstes_template/Resources/Public/Css/bootstrap.min.css
    }

    includeJSLibs {

    }

    includeJS {

    }

    includeJSFooterlibs {

    }

    includeJSFooter {
        erstes_template_scripts = EXT:erstes_template/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Dist/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
    }
}
```

Edit3: [image: Pagetree vs link output]

Comment: maybe you can add a page tree of your instance, to make clear what pages should be in the navigation visible and which site they belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can build your menus with typoscript, where you need to select which kind of links should be generated. A typical menu would be: show subpages from page with id (or in your case: show subpages from pages with ids from list), recursion level is optional.

The old way: use a [`HMENU` object](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html) and define the complete mark-up in typoscript.
Or the new way with a dataprocessor/ [menuprocessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/MenuProcessor.html)

In the first way you only need to assign the output to a fluid variable to include in your page template, or you call it with the [`f:cObject` viewhelper](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/11.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/CObject.html).

With the menuprocessor you get a fluid variable which contains an array with the links you can display with fluid (e.g. in a partial)

---

if you use further extensions (like [ext:vhs](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/vhs)) you may get viewhelpers which generate menus or at least the fluid variables with the menu data.

---

**ADD**:

```
page.10.dataProcessing {
   30 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
   30 {
      levels = 2
      as = headerMenu
      expandAll = 1
      includeSpacer = 1
      special = directory
      special.value = 12,23,34
   }
}
```

you might oversee the small hint in the documentation to `MenuProcessor` just before the [Example](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/MenuProcessor.html#example-two-level-menu-of-the-web-page):

```
Important
Additionally all HMENU options are available.
```

in the [HMENU options](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html#cobj-hmenu-options) you can find additional options to configure your menu. In this case I consider it a menu of the pages 12,23 and 34 with their subpages.
The important option is `special` with `special.value` where you control the kind of menu and which base pages are used.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I am struggling to implement the menuprocessor. The setup.typoscript is structured a bit different than the MenuProcessor.typoscript [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/MenuProcessor.html)

I don´t know where to put the "as = headerMenu" and the other lines, I tried some different ways but kept getting "Oops, an error occurred!", so I must have done something wrong...
Can you please tell me how I can implement the code correctly? (Code is in the original Question)

Comment: I added an example with further documentation links

Comment: Thank you, I really did miss the special parameter. Now it works!

However it only shows the links of the subpages, not the link to the parent page itself. Do you know how I can make it show links to the parent pages aswell?
I added an image with a comparison of the page tree and the links that show up in the question.

Comment: If you want to include the root pages of the subtrees you can use `special = list` instead of `directory`. Notice the additional level which might need an increased `level` option.

Comment: Right, its right below the documentation of "special = directory", my bad.
Everything works now, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to be on the safe side: Do you really mean `sites` (which would be several different domains within a single multisite tree) or are we actually talking about `pages`?

If it's `pages`, I guess what you are missing is the `expandAll` parameter, which is described here:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/MenuProcessor.html#confval-expandAll

> Should all submenus be included or only those of the active pages?

Comment: I do mean sites, I am pretty sure. I can see them in "Site Management -> Sites" in the Typo3 menu and they each have their own URL.
However I did need the expandAll parameter and I used it when creating the headerMenu, but I deleted it with the other parameters in the code snippet I showed, because the entire thing didn`t work. It was located at the "#I tried to implement the new code here!" part in "dataprocessing".
In hindsight I should have left my failed attempt as commented code to make things more clear.
Thank you for pointing it out though!